# how to solve it using dp top-down approach?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I was solving this problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/BYTESM2/ using dynamic-programming top-down approach,but getting WA.

is there any logical error?

can someone provide an insight in which case it's failing.Thank you.

```
int max1(int a,int b,int c)
{
    return max( max(a,b),c );
}

int main()
{

        int t;
        cin >> t;
        while(t--)
        {
            int r,c;
            cin >> r >> c;
            int dp[r][c+2]={0};
            int i,j;
            for(i=0;i<r;++i)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=c;++j)
                {
                   cin >> dp[i][j];
                }
            }

            for(i=1;i<r;++i)
            {
                for(j=1;j<=c;++j)
                {

                    dp[i][j] += max1( dp[i-1][j-1],dp[i-1][j],dp[i-1][j+1] );

                }
            }


            int m=-1;
            for(i=0;i<c;++i)
            {
                m = max(m,dp[r-1][i]);
            }

            cout << m << endl;

        }


}
```